# What is a value called, that signals that nothing has happened?

Tags: semantics, naming

I'm at a loss for what to call that or even what to search for.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
value = None

if something_is_true:
    value = 123

if value is not None:
    send(value)
```

What is the use of `None` called in this instance? In my head it sounds something like Cardinal Value, although that is not it.

Comment: I'd say "sentinel" or "guard", or even "canary", depending on what its semantic role is.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sentinel! Bingo.

Comment: Well, glad I could help :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Care to make it an answer? :)

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're probably looking for is "sentinel", that is a variable that triggers some behavior depending on whether it's set or not.

For further information see [Sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) on Wikipedia.